# Why did they turn Charizard into Ash's "starter"?

Tags: pokemon

People say they gave Ash a Pikachu because it would earn them more money if Ash had all three starters than just one starter. But then why did they make Charizard their starter representative later? Charizard was the only one that evolved from Ash's Kanto starters, the writers gave Gary a Blastoise to fight Ash's Charizard, in *Mewtwo Strikes Back* Ash is the one who represents Charizard while other trainers represent Venusaur and Blastoise, and in the *Pokémon Zencho* mangá and in the *I Choose You!* film, Ash has Charmander as his only starter.

Comment: may be bescasue the character "ash/santoshi" is loosly based on game character "red" and red's starter pokemon is charizard.

Comment: That would only put the question to another level on why the best representing character, red, has charizard. I think the reason that not all starters evolved is simply because of "diversity", as the hero and thus the series is more interesting if he is interesting on a different level than "MORE POWEER!", the reason now that it is exactly charizard which is chosen might also be connected to the points that a dragon is way cooler than a turtoise or a toad, and the rebel attitude of ash's charizard fits more to 'zard than to the calm or soft looking blastoise/venusaur.

Answer (score 0):

I think Charizard's popularity started when people got the tcg cards of a holographic shadowless card adn people making fun of how charizard is a fire/flying type who can't learn fly in the gen 1 games and people though CHarizard was a dragon type.

Answer (score 0):

I think that because Charizard is the easiest Pokemon to draw of the starter trio. If they wanted to pick a starter to be Ash's starter, They would have to spend a lot of time drawing that particular Pokemon. Ken Sugomori mentioned that he doesn't like to draw Venusaur because of its complexity. Blastoise is a bit more difficult to draw compared to Charizard. So, it will be easier to just let Charmander be Ash's starter.

Another reason which is Ash is an anime counterpart of Red. Red in the games owns a Charizard/Charmeleon/Charmander.